# Organize uploaded media files

Tags: multisite, uploads, media

I have a blog with all media stored in a folder called **upload** (organize media was disabled), I've activate it to organize new uploads by date. **But how can i organize old files?**

I want this because i need to migrate the site to a Wordpress MU site, and i need to have files organizated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thans but I've found the solution, what it need to do is to edit the site **(Network -> Sites -> Edit -> Settings )** and change the following parameters:

```
Uploads Use Yearmonth Folders   0
Upload Path                     wp-content/blogs.dir/1/uploads
Fileupload Url                  http://www.mydomain.com/myblog/uploads
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this plugin can help: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-filemanager/

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please describe at least what the plugin does. And screenshots are upvote magnets. ;)

Comment: Thanks, but i wanted is to migrate files easily and keeping the one folder configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can hard-code this change for all your sites like this:
1. Create a new php file with a path like this: wp-content/mu-plugins/no_date_assets.php
If the wp-content/mu-plugins folder does not already exist, you will have to manually create it.
2. In that file paste the following:

```
<?php

$uploads_use_yearmonth_folders = get_option( 'uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', 1 );

if ( $uploads_use_yearmonth_folders ) {
    update_option( 'uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', 0 );
}
```

That's all!
This will make all future uploads not use the year/month folders.